# Find a sequence from text file into Xml file - Java / variable from bash

Tags: java, xml, bash, shell, java.util.scanner

I need to find a text sequence that is writting into a text file, into many xml files.

The variable that contains every xml to process, cames from a bash script, and its : ${filearray[$i]}

I need to print the names of this xml files that does NOT contain the text sequence.

Below the code of the script from where i will get the XML files:

```
function check()
{



    # http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

    OLDIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    # Read all pom files into an array
    # - Search for repositories
    # - Exclude folders
    fileArray=($(find . -type f -not -path "./folder1/*" -not -path "*/folder2/*" -not -path "./.repository/*" -name "pom.xml" \
                    | xargs grep -P "<module>" \
                    -H -n))
    IFS=$OLDIFS

    # get length of an array
    numberOfFiles=${#fileArray[@]}

    # read all filenames
    for (( i=0; i<${numberOfFiles}; i++ ));
    do
      echo "ERROR:Found repository definitions (file:line:occurrence): ${fileArray[$i]}"
    done


if [ "$numberOfFiles" != "0" ]; then
    echo "SUMMARY:Found $numberOfFiles pom.xml file(s) containing repository definitions."
    exit 1
fi
}


check
```

I am using Scanner class to read the external file secuence:

```
    package com.mypackage.usercodeinpoms;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ExternalFileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //file instance to reference text file 
        File text = new File("/home/user/temp/foo.txt");

        //Creating Scanner instance to read file
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

        //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
            lineNumber++;
        }       

    }  


    }
```

Comment: Put the code what you have written in bash then we can suggest you based on that. Also the explanation is not clear to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answser. I added the code. I need to find into those pom.xml files ; that there is a text secuence into them. I guess i need to store that text into other external file. If they dont contain it "exactly", print out their names.

Comment: I added the class im using to read into the text file. How can I link both? Search this text into pom files, and print those NOT contaning it?

Comment: some tips? im stucked there. Thanks :)